# how to enable kpti or kvas

Tags: windows, 64-bit

How to enable KvaShadow(KPTI)， my computer cpu is intel， system is Windows 10

i want to enable kpti, but i don't konw how to enable it. i search a crticle that it say modify reg, but enable kpti or kvas!   the detail of that article is
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management" /v FeatureSettingsOverride /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management" /v FeatureSettingsOverrideMask /t REG_DWORD /d 3 /f